# VS Code jupyter notebook forward cell output to new text tab or to an external program

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, hdf5

I want to investigate some NeXus files in a jupyter notebook.

```
from nexusformat.nexus import *
expmlfile = r"...\NXsas.hdf5" 
with nxopen(expmlfile) as f:
     print(f.tree)
```

Because the output is quite large, it is truncated, but the option to open it in a text editor is available. It is possible to forward the output to a new VS Code tab or Notepad++ programmatically?